# foreach creates duplicate tables in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have a query that gives this array,

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [name] => name1 
    )

    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 2 
        [name] => name2 
    ) 

    [2] => Array ( 
        [id] => 3 
        [name] => name3 
    )
 )
```

When this is returned to a HTML page and made a foreach, It duplicates the table into 3 tables .

```
<?php foreach ($types AS $row_types) { ?>
<table class="table_style1">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Title2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php $row_types['name'][0]?></td>
        <td>data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php $row_types['name'][1]?></td>
        <td>data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php $row_types['name'][2]?></td>
        <td>data 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

please help me to show only 1 table here.

Comment: Put the `table` tag and the heading `tr` outside from the loop.

Comment: @S.I.  then the table rows duplicate

Comment: @FrayneKonok then the table rows duplicate

Comment: Don't *list* all rows *by hand*. That is what your `foreach` should be doing.

Comment: @tenten, Okey then let me make an answer for you.

Comment: use only one time `tr` no need to put more then once. it will automatically create rows for you .

Comment: @Yoshi the table is not well listed for taken out data by for each in a pattern

Comment: @tenten, I posted an answer for you, take a look and let me know your expectation.

Comment: @tenten. I have provided with the solution. Share thoughts and let me know if you face any hindrance

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you're not understanding how the `foreach` works. It takes your array and runs through the code inside the `foreach` once per entry in your array.

With your array structure the `foreach` will go through each element of your array `$types` one at a time. As the elements in `$types` are arrays themselves (i.e. you have a multi-dimensional array) `$row_types` will be an array containing the keys `id` and `name`. As we only want one table with one row per array we need to initiate the table and it's title outside of the `foreach` loop.

```
<table class="table_style1">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Title2</th>
    </tr>
```

Then we can have our `foreach` output each row for us

```
<?php foreach ( $types as $row_types ) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $row_types['id'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row_types['name'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

If you notice I'm using `<?=` tags, this is a shortcut for `<?php echo` because at the moment you're not echoing out what is in row, you've just put the variable and done nothing with it.

Finally we can close the table

```
</table>
```

The whole code will look like this

```
<table class="table_style1">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Title2</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ( $types as $row_types ) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $row_types['id'] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row_types['name'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: @FrayneKonok Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `table` tag and the heading `tr th` outside from the loop.

```
$types = array ( 
            array ( 
                "id" => 1,
                "name" => "name1"
            ),
            array ( 
                "id" => 2,
                "name" => "name2"
            ),
            array ( 
                "id" => 3,
                "name" => "name3"
            )
        );
?>
<table class="table_style1">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Title2</th>
    </tr>
<?php 
foreach ($types AS $row_types) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo$row_types['name'];?></td>
        <td>data <?php echo $row_types['id']?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error:** You have used the table to **repeat inside** the `forach()` loop and hence it is the error in your script.

**Needed Corrections:** `<table>` and `<tr>` should **start outside** and **end outside** the loop `to avoid the duplicates` that you face now. `</tr>` and `</table>`

Hence i will provide you with the Example Below:

**Example:**

```
<table>
<?php
foreach()
{
}
?>
</table>
```

### Solution for: foreach creates duplicate tables in HTML

Your entire code will look like as follows as i have told above the table and tr will start before the foreach loop.

**Code:**

```
<table class="table_style1">
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>NAME</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($types AS $row_types) { ?>        
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row_types['id']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_types['name']?></td>
    </tr>        
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You've still left the 3 rows inside the foreach. OP wants one table with 3 rows, not 9 rows.

Comment: Please check now. whether it is correct . I hope so it is correct @Styphon